# load json file at runtime in webpack

Tags: webpack, external

I am new into Webpack and my requirement is to include any JSON file at runtime not in bundled file using webpack.

Scenario:
--I have to write code like this in webpack.config.js:

```
externals: {
    Conf: JSON.stringify(require('./env/env-dev.json'))
}
```

In another Component file, we require like this:--

```
    const config = require('Conf');
```

But in this code env-dev.json has loaded in bundled file when we require 'Conf' under any component module.

But when we don't require it in any component, then this env-dev.json will not be loaded in bundled file.

But my requirement is don't want to include this file under bundled file. and use it any code.

Please help me out..

Answer (score -1):

A sample jQuery Function to read JSON from a file:

```
var conf;
$.getJSON( 
      jsonFilePathOrURL,
      function(result, status, xhr) {
                conf = result;
             //..here conf is a JSON variable.....................///
             //...you can get string using JSON.stringify(conf); ///
      }
 );
```

Comment: I need the solution using Webpack either using external or another plugin.